# How to integrate PHP project with a HTML project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp

So, I have been working on a static web project in VS Code, as I am just getting into web dev I didn't focus too much on the backend. A friend helped me out by working on PHP and MySQL, making a local server on XAMPP and running it on a browser.

However, now I'd like to integrate that PHP project with the one that I've been working on. For example, I have a "Log In" nav item in the nav bar and what I'd like to do is when I click on "Log In", it should show the PHP project.

I did add the "php.validate.executablePath" in the settings, pointing to the php.exe in the XAMPP folder. Also, here's what I tried by myself to make this work but this just opens the whole code in the browser. The PHP project folder is placed in the project folder that I'm working on.

```
<li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" a href="../bootstrap/Job-Portal/index.php">Log In</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter `ext install felixfbecker.php-pack`

Comment: @theBuzzyCoder What else should be done? Just did this, but the results are still the same.

Comment: are you accessing through localhost? `(http://localhost/<your project folder name in xampp/htdocs>) ` example: `http://localhost/my-project-1`

Comment: @Ramshid I'm truly an idiot. Thanks for the help, it's working now. Just added the path, like you mentioned, in the a href.

Comment: BilalHakim I presume that the issue is resolved with answer of @ramshid.